# Thinking Sphinx can't find Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to make a Rails 3 application that uses Sphinx by way of thinking-sphinx. In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'
```

When I do a rails server, here's the error I get:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name
```

Any ideas for how I can fix this? I've tried making a sphinx.yml file but it still doesn't help:

```
development: 
  bin_path: "/usr/local/bin" 
  searchd_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/searchd"
  indexer_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/indexer"
test:
  bin_path: "/usr/local/bin" 
  searchd_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/searchd"
  indexer_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/indexer"
production:
  bin_path: "/usr/local/bin" 
  searchd_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/searchd"
  indexer_binary_name: "/usr/local/bin/indexer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an error that occurs when Sphinx isn't properly installed, which was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

2.x releases of Thinking Sphinx work with Rails 3.0 - though I'd recommend also upgrading to the latest 3.0.x release of Rails so you've got most of the latest security fixes.